# attach PDF woocommerce email

Tags: wordpress, pdf, woocommerce

I would like to attach a PDF to the customer-processing-order from Woocommerce, I have tried the following:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10,  3);
function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments, $status ,  $order ) {
    $allowed_statuses = array('customer_processing_order');
    if( isset( $status ) && in_array ( $status, $allowed_statuses ) ) {
        $your_pdf_path = get_template_directory() . '/terms.pdf';
        $attachments[] = $pdf_path;
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```

and I have uploaded a PDF called terms.pdf into my child theme so path is
`/wp-content/themes/child-theme/terms.pdf`, but is not working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating the path to your PDF and assigning it to a variable named `$your_pdf_path` but then you add a variable to the `$attachments` array called `$pdf_path`. You can simplify this without using a temporary variable like so:

```
$attachments[] = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/terms.pdf';
```

Comment: Template directory will always point to the parent theme. The OP suggests a child theme so I believe [get_stylesheet_directory() ](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) is in order.