# Attach a PDF from Order custom field to Order email woocommerce

Tags: php, pdf, woocommerce, email-attachments

I'm looking to attach a pdf from a custom field in my order to an order email.

I've created the field using PODs, however I can't work out how to attach it to the order email.

Any pointers would be great.

I've found this article [attach PDF woocommerce email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444223/attach-pdf-woocommerce-email) however it is to attach a single PDF to all emails, rather than getting the PDF from the order meta.

Thanks